# Exit function after events

Tags: javascript, function, titanium, onload, onload-event

I want to have my own initialization function, and I want it exit only after onload event, what can I do for it?

```
var qqq=0;
function init(){
    var requestClient= Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    requestClient.open('GET','https://mysite.com/api/123/id/5/friends');
        requestClient.onload = function() {
            alert('loaded');
        };
    requestClient.send();
};
init();
alert(qqq);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* do that, by making the request synchronous instead of asynchronous. This has unpleasant side-effects on the user's browsing experience, tending to lock things up during the request, but if you set [`open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-open)'s third argument to `false`, it will make it synchronous instead of asynchronous:

```
var qqq=0;
function init(){
    var requestClient= Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    requestClient.open('GET','https://mysite.com/api/123/id/5/friends', false);
                                                           // Here------^
        requestClient.onload = function() {
            alert('loaded');
        };
    requestClient.send();
};
init();
alert(qqq);
```

A synchronous request will bring the JavaScript execution on the page (at least, and in many browsers rather more than just the JavaScript) to a screeching halt until the network operation completes.

**But** the usual practice is to have your `init` accept a callback you call from within the `onload` handler, as this makes for a much better UX:

```
var qqq=0;
function init(callback){  // <== Accept a callback
    var requestClient= Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    requestClient.open('GET','https://mysite.com/api/123/id/5/friends');
        requestClient.onload = function() {
            alert('loaded');
            callback();   // <== Call the callback
        };
    requestClient.send();
};
init(function() {         // <== Pass the callback into `init`
    alert(qqq);
});
```

Effective web programming is about embracing the event-driven nature of it. I'd strongly recommend the second example.

Comment: FYI: Appcelerator's implementation of the httpClient does not support the third argument

Comment: @Aaron: Really? Doesn't say that in [the docs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.open-method.html). But I have to admit I completely missed that this was using Titanium. :-) All the more reason to go with the "But the usual practice is..." option!